# How to get a Search Pop-up to Work With New Menu Layout and Code?

Tags: javascript, search, popup

I'm trying to create a new menu for a site that is live and has a `pop-up search bar`. Everything works as far as the search on the current site/version. I added the new menu code to a dev page along with the code for the search.

I can't seem to get the search to pop-up/show when the magnify glass button is clicked. I'm confused.

Here is the `html` code that I'm using for the search:

```
<div class="hidden-xs navbar-form navbar-right">
    <a href="#search" class="search-form-tigger btn btn-success"  data-toggle="search-form"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></div>               
<div class="search-form-wrapper">
    <form class="search-form" id="siq_searchForm" action="">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="search" name="s" class="search form-control" value="" placeholder="Type here to search...">
            <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon2"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

And here is the `JS` that I'm using to get the pop-up to work:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('[data-toggle=search-form]').click(function() {
  $('.search-form-wrapper').toggleClass('open');
  $('.search-form-wrapper .search').focus();
  $('html').toggleClass('search-form-open');
});

$('[data-toggle=search-form-close]').click(function() {
    $('.search-form-wrapper').removeClass('open');
    $('html').removeClass('search-form-open');
});

$('.search-form-wrapper .search').keypress(function( event ) {
    if($(this).val() == "Search") $(this).val("");
});

$('.search-close').click(function(event) {
    $('.search-form-wrapper').removeClass('open');
    $('html').removeClass('search-form-open');
});
```

Also here is a [link](https://www.unitedradiocomm.com/index-menu-test.htm) to the dev page.

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The code for the search popup is valid and works, it is just not getting executed. I believe the issue is that you have code which is causing an error and interrupting the rest of your JS. Take a look in the browser console and you'll see:

```
index-menu-test.htm:2019 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).loopSlider is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (index-menu-test.htm:2019)
    at j (jquery.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:2)
    at Function.ready (jquery.js:2)
    at HTMLDocument.I (jquery.js:2)
```

I'd need more information on what libraries you're using to competently diagnose that issue, but I suspect if you fix that, your menu will work correctly.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this issue. I guess what's so confusing to me is that the search works here (with current nav): https://www.unitedradiocomm.com. But when I added the new nav, mainly css and a few div's, it breaks. And that url is here: https://www.unitedradiocomm.com/index-menu-test.htm. Ugh.

Comment: You are correct, when I rem out the JS that includes the "loopSlider," the search pop-up works! Let me see if I can figure out if that code is even needed. Thanks again!!